# ASP.Net Web pages available only on LAN

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

I have asp.net web application and i want people can use it only from my company network ( LAN ) , how can i make it??

Comment: Most companies use NAT boxes and outside users can't access machines on their intranets. Ask you network administrator if you are behind a NAT

Answer (score 3):

You can

- use a firewall to block the outcome connections ! This is the most secure.
- Use login page and allow only register users.
- The less secure way, is to check for the ips of each connection inside you application.

To check the ips, on BeginRequest, you read the client IP, you check if its [in a range of the private networs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) or you place what other ips you like, and if its not you just close the connection:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPrivateNetwork(MyCurrentContent.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"])
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        return ;    
    }
}


public bool IsPrivateNetwork(string sMyIpString)
{
    long TheIpTranslate = AddressToNum(sMyIpString);

    if (TheIpTranslate >= 0)
    {
        // 192.168.0.0 192.168.255.255
        if (TheIpTranslate >= 3232235520 && TheIpTranslate <= 3232301055)
            return true;

        // 10.0.0.0 10.255.255.255
        if (TheIpTranslate >= 167772160 && TheIpTranslate <= 184549375)
            return true;

        // 172.16.0.0 172.31.255.255
        if (TheIpTranslate >= 2886729728 && TheIpTranslate <= 2887778303)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public long AddressToNum(string cAddress)
{
    IPAddress MyIpToCheck = null;

    if (IPAddress.TryParse(cAddress, out MyIpToCheck))
    {
        return AddressToNum(MyIpToCheck);
    }
    else
    {
        return -1;
    }
}


public long AddressToNum(IPAddress Address)
{
    byte[] b = BitConverter.GetBytes(Address.Address);

    if (b.Length == 8)
        return (long)(((long)16777216 * b[0]) + ((long)(65536 * b[1])) + ((long)(256 * b[2])) + b[3]);
    else
        return 0;
}
```